# exact year to select with bash script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I am working on following script which throws an error if the year is not in digits with exact 4 digits.

so far, I have below code but the only problem is it accepting more digits than 4 which I want to limit it to 4 digits only.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter year " y
while [[ -z $y || $y =~ [A-Za-z]+ || ! $y =~ [0-9]{4} ]]; do
            read -p "Enter the year in a valid format [yyyy] " y
done
echo "Selected year is: $y"
```

output -

```
 Enter the year in a valid format [yyyy] vrgege
 Enter the year in a valid format [yyyy] vegter
 Enter the year in a valid format [yyyy] 123
 Enter the year in a valid format [yyyy] 12345
 Selected year is: 12345
```

It not accepting less than 4 digits but it accepting more than 4 digits.

Can anyone suggest, how to put a condition to get exact only 4 digits?

Comment: In my opinion, this can be removed: `-z $y || $y =~ [A-Za-z]+ ||`

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
[0-9]{4}
```

by

```
^[0-9]{4}$
```

to match only exact four numbers.

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Or use a glob pattern with the == operator: `$y == [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Comment: Yes, that is possible, too.

Answer (score 0):

Without bashisms, for portability, I suggest

```
case $y in
([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])
   printf "A four digit year, OK\n"
   ;;
([0-9][0-9][0-9])
   printf "A three digit year, OK\n"
   ;;
([0-9][0-9])
   printf "A two digit year, OK\n"
   ;;
([0-9])
   printf "A one digit year, OK\n"
   ;;
(*)
   printf "NOT OK\n"
esac
```

You can also combine these with `(...|...|...|...)` if you wish.